# How to fix .Evaluate rounding result

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate, thomson-reuters-eikon

I am using `Evaluate` in order to execute this formula  :

```
x = Application.Evaluate("AdInterp(" & cells(2,"C").value & "," & "'" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fonction DCF ").Range("U8:U31").Parent.Name & "'!" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fonction DCF ").Range("U8:U31").Address(external:=False) & "," & "'" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fonction DCF ").Range("V8:V31").Parent.Name & "'!" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fonction DCF ").Range("V8:V31").Address(external:=False) & ",IM:CUBD)")
```

It returns 1 (Seems that the `.Evaluate` round result). **The excepted output is** : 1,00042406864688

`x` is a `double` type so i don't understand why the result is rounded ... any idea ?

### Question :

Did I make a mistake building the formula in order to evaluate it ?

---

## Below several test that I have done

When I put the formula in a cells the output is : **1,00042406864688**

Excel worksheet formula :

```
=AdInterp(C2;'Fonction DCF '!U8:U31;'Fonction DCF '!V8:V31;IM:CUBD)
```

Execution Window :

[image]

**Note :** When I put formula in cells and I do

```
Evaluate(Cells(2,"G").Formula)
```

the output is :  **1,00042406864688**

[image]

Comment: `cells(2,"C")` is poiting to the sheet you want (Activesheet)?

Comment: @FunThomas sure it is. My problem is that the result is rounded to 1 but i don't want it to be rounded

Comment: @FunThomas  I edited My issue maybe its more clear

Comment: Going to be hard to reproduce but several issues perhaps: use `Worksheet.Evaluate` instead of `Application.Evaluate`. Then `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fonction DCF ").Range("U8:U31").Parent.Name` can be simplified to just `"Fonction DCF "`.

Comment: @BigBen Yeah I know but its an interpolation formula from reuters, I can't make a reproducible example

Comment: Why do you use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fonction DCF ").Range("U8:U31").Parent.Name` - this will resolve in the sheetname, so why not use "Fonction DCF " directly? Same for the Range address. Write the formula into a variable, check it with the debugger and pass the variable to the `Evaluate` function.  `Evaluate` itself does not round anything (easily to show with `evaluate("3/4")`

Comment: Can `AdInterp` not be invoked directly?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon How would You do ? `Cells.formula = ` ?

Comment: No, via the API, e.g. [like this](https://community.developers.refinitiv.com/questions/17527/how-to-call-adinterp-in-vba-code.html)?

Comment: No, I mean `x = AdInterp(args)`. You're making the Excel calc engine evaluate a function, but you're already in code, the calc engine doesn't need to get involved - just invoke the function *if it's in scope* (see @BigBen's comment above, looks like it's indeed possible just need to import the function from the DLL).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Sure I will pass by the DLL then, I will give u feedbacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider [invoking the function directly](https://community.developers.refinitiv.com/questions/17527/how-to-call-adinterp-in-vba-code.html), rather than getting the calculation engine to evaluate it.

But it *should* work regardless. I suspect it's working, even - but [implicit ActiveSheet references](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference) are throwing a wrench into it.

This `Cells` member call isn't qualified:

```
& cells(2,"C").value &
```

That's implicitly referring to cells on *whatever the active worksheet is*. Contrast with:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fonction DCF ") & "!" ...
```

That means the input array being passed to the function depends on what sheet is active when that instruction runs, so if the intent is to work off the "Fonction DCF " sheet, I'd recommend being explicit about it.

Select the "Fonction DCF " sheet module in the *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R), then press F4 to bring up the *Properties* toolwindow, and look at the `(Name)` property of that sheet. If it says `Sheet1` (or similar - that's the default), change it to `FonctionDCFSheet`, then change your code to refer to that sheet using its programmatic name (I'm assuming the sheet exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time) - also as @FunThomas aptly suggested, consider pulling the dynamically-evaluated string into its own local variable, to make it easier to debug:

```
With FonctionDCFSheet
    Dim dynamicEval As String
    dynamicEval = "AdInterp(" & .Cells(2,"C").value & "," & _
                  "'" & .Name & "'!U8:U31," & _
                  "'" & .Name & "'!V8:V31, IM:CUBD)"
    Debug.Print dynamicEval
    x = .Evaluate(dynamicEval)
End With
```

(line continuations to reduce horizontal scrolling)

Note that I also cleaned up / removed a number of extraneous steps: you don't need to get a `Range` of cells and then get the `Parent` of that `Range` to get the `Name` of a `Worksheet` you're already dereferencing by name, and you don't need to get the `Address` of a `Range` for a range of cells you're already dereferencing by address.

Also because we're invoking `Worksheet.Evaluate` now (the `.Evaluate` call is qualified by the `With` block variable), the string formula gets evaluated *in the context of that sheet*, so the sheet-naming within the string becomes superfluous and the string can be further simplified:

```vb
    CreateAdxUtilityModule.AdInterp(Periode, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fonction DCF ").Range("U8:U31").Value, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fonction DCF ").Range("V8:V31").Value, "IM:CUBR")

'Periode  is a date format dim
```

And just now I'm noticing that the last part `IM:CUBD` is also being evaluated unqualified; with `Application.Evaluate` that is passing `IM:CUBD` of the `ActiveSheet`; with `Worksheet.Evaluate` that is passing the same columns, but always on the correct sheet, no matter which sheet is active.

Comment: I would still advocate to write the formula into an intermediate variable (and check it with a `Debug.Print`) before throwing it to the `Evaluate`-Function.

Comment: Invoking the function solve my issue. But with calculation engine i still have the same issue, thank you

Comment: @Dorian does the last snippet work as intended though? I fully expected the direct invoke to work, but I'm curious whether the implicit ActiveSheet references had something to do with the unexpected outputs :)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon nop I had to modify it and to add reference to my wokbook to... and the syntax I used is slightly different, i will suggest an edit :)

Comment: @Dorian aye, `FunctionDCFSheet` would be undefined if you don't make that the sheet's `(Name)` - there is no need to pull from `Worksheets` by name, a sheet that exists at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook` =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon i know :)